# Wireless adaptors won't work. inspiron 8500. Cisco adaptors

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell

i have 2 wireless notebook adaptors and neither work on my Dell inspiron 8500. i've tried going to settings and it says no proprietary drivers are being used.i have a Cisco Air-PCM352 and a Linksys Wireless-G WPC54G. Help

Comment: could you insert the adapters and run: sudo lshw and post the relevant data here?

Comment: for the Linksys WPC54G, it reads:

Comment: for the Linksys WPC54G:*-network UNCLAIMED
          description: Network controller
          product: ACX 111 54Mbps Wireless Interface
          vendor: Texas Instruments
          physical id: 1
          bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pm cap_list
          configuration: latency=0
          resources: memory:28020000-28021fff memory:28000000-2801ffff

Comment: For the AIR-PCM352:  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth1
       serial: 00:0a:b7:4c:c7:3b
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=airo_cs multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11-DS

Comment: Ok, we continue with the AIR-PCM, this one is recognized.
I'll switch over to the answer section and will edit my answer when you update your question, this gives a bit more visual possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The asked `sudo lshw |grep -A 15 network` gives:

For the AIR-PCM352:

> *-network description: Wireless interface physical id: 1 logical name: eth1 serial: 00:0a:b7:4c:c7:3b capabilities: ethernet physical
>   wireless configuration: broadcast=yes driver=airo_cs multicast=yes
>   wireless=IEEE 802.11-DS

For the Linksys WPC54G:

> *-network UNCLAIMED description: Network controller product: ACX 111 54Mbps Wireless Interface vendor: Texas Instruments physical id: 1 bus
>   info: pci@0000:03:00.0 version: 00 width: 32 bits clock: 33MHz
>   capabilities: pm cap_list configuration: latency=0 resources:
>   memory:28020000-28021fff memory:28000000-2801ffff

So we use the AIR-PCM, ifconfig gives only a link on eth0, not on eth1:

> > eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr
> >     xx:xx:xx:xx inet addr:192.168.2.111 Bcast:192.168.2.255
> >     Mask:255.255.255.0

So we now know the AIR-PCM is being recognized and bound to the driver airo_cs but is not assigned to an ip address.

Access the network-manager icon in the upper right corner, hopefully you can see wireless networks to which you can connect. If not, run `nm-connection-editor` and try to setup eth1.

Comment: Ok,I updated the data which I need in your question, please remove your comments with ifconfig because the inet6 addr could be traceable. (Probably not, but I have no time at the moment to verify and I do not need the rest of the data in the comments)
I'll pick this up tomorrow.

Comment: thank you. i wish i understood what the info in ifconfig means.

Comment: It shows if and to which address your network device is assigned. In most cases this is only like the room number in your house, used to coordinate traffic within the house but useless if you do not know the street address. With ipv6 all rooms get their own street address, so if your provider supports ipv6 (unlikely) we could knock on the door of your computer.